# Disable mkl inside eigen

Tags: tensorflow, system, eigen, bazel

System information

OS Platform and Distribution : Debian GNU/Linux 10

TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): Source

TensorFlow version:latest

Python version:3.7.3

Installed using virtualenv? pip? conda?: virtualenv

Bazel version (if compiling from source):3.3.0

GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source): gcc 8.3

I did **NOT** use the --config=mkl flag while building

The image is a call graph of 1024X1024 Matmul done 100 times, if you look carefully mkldnn_sgemm is called internally by Eigen, this is what I want to disable.

[image: internal_eigen]

After some amount of reading I found out that MKL can be called internally by Eigen and after reading the Bazel documentation and seeing how TensorFlow is strucured.I want to disable mkl/mkl_dnn completely if eigen is to be used.
The Eigen build files [loads the ifmkl symbol from the mkl directory](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/bd35e19edbf55bf3f6b5d10545725d41a99aa9ba/third_party/eigen3/BUILD#L5).
My next step was to look at the [if_mkl function inside the build_defs.bzl](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c63b59ce648b525c4bbb2d85f04f5b71f1849ff2/third_party/mkl/build_defs.bzl#L17)

I changed the [includes attribute in the cclibrary rule in the BUILD file of eigen](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/44aace846df438bf55e88dad1e047b7c81f9efb9/third_party/eigen3/BUILD#L36) to ["//conditions:default"] and tried building it again

which game me an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'portpicker'`

So pip installed portpicker `pip install portpicker`
And the build completed sucessfully after I did this, but the profile literally shows no difference mkldnn_sgemm is still bieng called the same number of time by eigen internally.

NOTE: **The Ultimate aim is to disable mkldnn which is bieng called from inside eigen**

Comment: What commands did you use to build tensorflow? If you look at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#preconfigured_configurations, it looks like mkl is not enabled by default unless you pass `--config=mkl`.

Comment: Yeah so I **did not pass the that --config=mkl**, but here is a call-graph of a program that does 1024X1024 Matrix Multiplication.
As you can see mkldnn_sgemm is being called internally by Eigen to perform sgemm
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zb7Ww7F82zeocaURhr0VXZ-R_PDCyq2Z/view?usp=sharing)